# Differences in these syntaxes for CSS?

Tags: html, css, class

I was wondering if you guys could help me get my head around what these actual syntax structures do in CSS, as I am really struggling to get my head around them.

**A.** A general style for all input elements

```
#input
{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: none;
}
```

**B.** ??????

```
 .input
{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: none;
}
```

**C.** A form input within a table element

```
table input
{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: none;
}
```

**D.** ???

```
table .input
{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: none;
}
```

**E.** ??????????

```
table input[type="text"] 
{
   width:100%;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: none;
}
```

Am I right in thinking these all achieve the same result, with respect to stlying the "input" element?

What would be the respective html code for each?

When does **"class"** or **"id"** apply to these?

Sorry if this seems like a basic question but I am trying to understand the best practices for CSS and learning 960 Grid Square is a bit hard when I see all these different CSS notations.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You need to read some tutorials about CSS selectors.

Comment: SO is not for tutorial,better try here :-www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: @Pranav ref: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: There is a lot of information about this on the web and it would not take long to read it for yourself.

Comment: I beg to differ, each say their way is the right way.

Comment: @loosebruce: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Well one website well tell you to do something is CSS one way and on another site they say another method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` symbol indicates that it's an ID selector, so it will only apply to the single element that has that particular ID on the page. You're incorrect about example A - that's actually a selector for the element with the ID `input`, not a general selector for all inputs.

The `.` symbol indicates that it's a class selector, so it will apply to all elements that have that class.

The `[type="text"]` is an attribute selector, so it will only select input elements that have a type attribute with a value equal to `text`.

Comment: An actual answer about the "syntax" , well done sir!

Answer (score 3):

**A**. A element with `id="input"`

```
#input
```

**B**. Elements with `class="input"`

```
.input
```

**C**. A form input within a table element

```
table input
```

**D**. Elements with `class="input"` inside a table

```
table .input
```

**E**. Input elements with the attribute `type="text"` inside a table

```
table input[type="text"]
```

All [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) are explained by w3 or a bit easier to read on [tutplus](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/).

**What is the best?**

There is no general best here. It depends on what you want to do. If you have a form with some inputs you want to style you could go with `#formid input`. But you might have different input elements where your default style does not work. `type="radio"` might need a different style than a `type="text"`.

Comment: **A** is incorrect - that's an ID selector for the element with ID `input`.

Comment: What is the difference then between a selector and a class coming from a C++ background?

Comment: Forget your C++ here. A class in HTML is an attribute on a element like <input class="error">. A selector in CSS describes what elements are affected by your style. Classes help you to apply styles over many elements. For example you add an error class to every form element the user did something wrong. Then you can use CSS to make all error field red.

Answer (score 1):

A => element with id 'input'

b => element/s with class 'input'

c => input field/s in table

d => element in table with class 'input'

e => text field/s in table

Answer (score 0):

Those are different selectors in CSS

"#input" ----------        means you are selecting element with id = "input"

".input"    -----------     you are selecting class = "input"

"table input"------    means you are selecting every input tag that is in table tag

and so on...

And yes take a look at some tutorials

Answer (score 0):

They are different selectors in CSS.

The . indicates a class that can be assigned to many elements. The # refers to an Id which means in order to maintain valid HTML it can only be used on one element. You access a # set of attributes by using the ID part of the html tag.

Using # has its limitations and is not widely used due to this.

Answer (score 0):

- a. styles an element by ID
- b. styles an element by class
- c. styles any input element found nested within any form element
- d. styles any element with a class of 'input' found inside any form
- e. styles an input with a type of 'text' within a form

Answer (score 0):

```
#input
{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: none;
}
```

Ans : element with id=input

```
.input
{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: none;
}
```

Ans: elements with class=input

```
table input
{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: none;
}
```

Ans: input elements inside table elements

```
table .input
{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: none;
}
```

Ans: elements with class=input which are inside table elements

```
table input[type="text"] 
{
   width:100%;
   border: 1px solid #000;
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: none;
}
```

Ans: input elements with type=text inside table elements

Answer (score 0):

A: You are targetting an element with the ID of "input", i.e. `<input id="input" />`
B: Same as before, now it's a class, i.e. `<input class="input" />`
C: A form input within a table element
D: An element with a class of "input" within a table
E: An input element with the type of "text" within a table, i.e. `<input type="text" />`(within a table).

I'd really recommend you pick up some books on basic HTML and CSS.

Comment: Maybe I have already done that but because many tutorials online conflict with each other it is hard to find out which is the best way to do things.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link [w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp](http://w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)
Your css is incorrect in case A: it should be just input not #input. # means your selecting by id. B means that your selecting by class